# How to find whole graph coverage path in dynamic state-flow diagram?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

As I've been researching algorithms for path finding in graph, I found interesting problem.

Definition of situation:

1)State diagram can have p states, and s Boolean Fields, and z Int Fields

2)Every state can have q ingoing and r outgoing transitions, and h Int fields (h belongs to z - see above)

3)Every transition can have only 1 event, and only 1 action

4)every action can change n Boolean Fields, and x Int Fields

5)every event can have one trigger from combination of any count of Boolean Fields in diagram

6)Transition can be in OPEN/CLOSED form. If the transition is open/closed depends on trigger2 compounded from 0..c Boolean fields.

7) I KNOW algorithm for finding shortest paths from state A to state B.

8) I KNOW algorithm for finding path that covers all states and transitions of whole state diagram, if all transitions are OPEN.

Now, what is the goal:

I need to find shortest path that covers all states and transitions in dynamically changing state diagram described above. When an action changes some int field, the algorithm should go through all states that have changed int field.
The algorithm should also be able to open and close transition (by going through transitions that open and close another transitions by action) in the way that the founded path will be shortest and covers all transitions and states.

Any idea how to solve it? I will be really pleased for ANY idea. Thanks for answers.

Comment: puh, would you mind to formulate this as a graph problem with (directed?) edges (+ weights) and nodes? what do you mean with state in this problem and what are events - what do they change? but maybe I completely miss the point ...

Comment: maybe you need to introduce a simple DAG subgraph from only possible states and calculate the shortest path there? but again: I didn't fully get the question, sorry :-(

Comment: This seems very localized.

Comment: a petri net might be a suitable model, taking states, booleans, ints, external event as PN places and transitions as PN transitions. event triggers are represented by edges from boolean PN places to PN transitions. the same holds for open/close triggers. actions are edges from PN transitions to booleans (possibly including PN inverters) and ints. aside, maintain a (multivalued) map from integer bins to states. add the start assignment (current state, boolean assignment, possibly some external events, set PN places for integers empty) and simulate the PN into a steady state. obtain ...

Comment: ... 'interesting' states from all PN places for integer bins with pebbles. open transitions are precisely those whose open/close incoming PN arcs all originate with booleans whose PN places have a pebble. next kill all PN arcs linking states with closed transitions. consider the graph G=(V,E), V={ PN places representing states as vertices }, E={ (u,v) \in V | there is a open transition t with (u,t), (t,v) in the PN graph }. Apply your algo 8) to G. (i'm not sure I got the specs right, but the PN model should get you started anyway. notes: non-determinism and no guarantee for a steady state).